# How do I give reasons for a basis and dimension that I found?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the problem where I know the answers to the questions, but they ask a reason for it and award marks for the reason. And they are very straightforward questions that I have no clue what reasons to give. I have no idea what to write as reasons when answering these types of questions.

> **Question**
>
> Let $W= \mathrm{span}(u,v,w)$ where $u=(1,1,0)$, $v=(2,2,0)$ and $w=(0,0,1)$.
>
> **1.** Find a basis for $W$. Give a reason for your answer.
>
> *Answer*. Basis: $\mathrm{span}(u,w)$

But what is the reason?

> **2.** What is the dimension of $W$? Give a reason for your answer.
>
> *Answer*. Dimension: $3$

This is obvious to me, I don't know how to describe a reason to someone, when I look at the basis, I can see it clearly spans $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I can't give a reason.

Comment: Your answer to (2) is incorrect.

Comment: How do you express $(1,0,0)$ as a linear combination of these 3 vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $u, v, w$ are not linearly independent (in fact $v=2u$). Therefore,  $\operatorname{dim}(W)=\operatorname{dim}(span (u,v,w))=\operatorname{dim}(span(u,w))=2$, not $3$, and therefore, a base for $W$ would be any two linearly independent vectors that span $W$, for example $\{u,w\}$. (Recall that $\{u,w\}$ is said to be a base for $W$ if it spans $W$, and if $u$ and $w$ are linearly independent.)

Comment: edited over there!

Comment: The dimension is the number of linearly indp vectors needed to span the space